# How to create Horizontal scroll view with the TextField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, textfield, horizontalscrollview

I am new to the Blackberry Field, I want to create a customized Horizontal scroll view which should exactly looks like in the below image. Any Help will be Apprreciated

[image]

I am using Blackberry Simulator 9900, Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I guess Middle portion is ONLY scrollable, right ?

You must have one HorizontalFieldManager with HORIZONTAL_SCROLL ( Middle one )
e.g. `HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager( HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );`
add your custom field in this manager.

You must add hfm in Custom OuterManager.

For your reference I'm posting my own code here...

```
private class HScroll extends MainScreen{
        public HScroll() {
            super( USE_ALL_WIDTH );
            OuterManager father = new OuterManager( );
            LabelField ll = new LabelField("<");
            father.add(ll);
            HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager( HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
            for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
                ButtonField btn = new ButtonField(" i " + i);
                hfm.add(btn);
            }
            father.add(hfm);
            LabelField ll1 = new LabelField(">");
            father.add(ll1);
            add(father);
        }

        private class OuterManager extends net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager{

            public OuterManager() {
                super(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
            }

            protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

                int x = 0;
                Field ff = getField( 0 );
                Field ff2 = getField( 2 );
                setPositionChild(ff, x, 0);
                layoutChild(ff, ff.getPreferredWidth(), ff.getPreferredHeight());

                x = x + ff.getPreferredWidth();
                Field ff1 = getField( 1 );
                setPositionChild(ff1, x , 0);
                layoutChild(ff1, width - ff.getPreferredWidth() - ff2.getPreferredWidth() , ff1.getPreferredHeight());

                x = width - ff2.getPreferredWidth();
                setPositionChild(ff2, x, 0);
                layoutChild(ff2, ff2.getPreferredWidth(), ff2.getPreferredHeight());

                setExtent(width, height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is one more option to achieve this...Use of TableLayoutManager http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299

Comment: The side arrows (< and >) should probably be `ButtonField` objects, instead of `LabelFields`.

Comment: I realize that it's sample code.  The point of a Q+A site is to provide good samples, as answers.  If you use a `LabelField` to represent the end arrows, then the user can't click them to scroll, which is normal behaviour.

Comment: I think it is okay to use `LabelFields` for side arrows when all the items added on the `HorizontalFieldManager` are `ButtonFields`.